# Get $(this) option attribute on .children

Tags: jquery, this

I am trying to get an attribute value for an option when using the following code:

```
$('#select3,#select5,#select7,#select9,#select11')
    .children('option[value="'+ selectedDValue +'"]', this)
    .attr({'disabled': true,'data-subtext':$(this).attr("data-subtext") + '
    (postcode area saved in another zone)'});
```

However `$(this).attr("data-subtext")` is returning 'Undefined', hence the attribute is being printed as `data-subtext="Undefined (postcode area saved in another zone)"`. The option does have an attribute called `data-subtext` so I'm wondering why nothing is being returned?

Comment: create a fiddle link so that we can come to know the exact problem. or try like this:-`$('#select3,#select5,#select7,#select9,#select11').children('option[value="'+ selectedDValue +'"]').each(function(){
 $(this).attr({'disabled': true,'data-subtext':$(this).attr("data-subtext")+'(postcode area saved in another zone)'});
});`

Comment: unfortunately still returning undefined @Anant but thanks for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per current code `this` refers to `window` object not `option` thus its returning `undefined`.

You need use [`.attr(attributeName, fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and remove from `.children()` method.

```js
$(selector).children('option[value="' + selectedDValue + '"]').attr('data-subtext', function(index, value) {
  return value + ' (postcode area saved in another zone)'
});
```

Comment: perfect thank you Satpal and very useful explanation. Upvoted as soon as 5 minutes is up!